# connecting line like tree in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have following type data for human family:

```
indvidual <- c("John",  "Kris", "Peter",  "King",  "Marry",  "Renu", "Kim",    "Ken", "Lu")
Parent1 <- c(    NA,     NA,     "John",  "John",   "John",    NA,    "Peter",  NA,    NA)
Parent2 <- c(    NA,     NA,    "Kris",   "Kris",  "Renu",   NA,      "Lu",     NA,   NA)
X <-       c(    2,     3,       2,       3,           4,     5,        1.5,      1,    1)
Y <-       c(    3,     3,       2,       2,           2,     3,        1,      3,    2)
pchsize <- c( 4.5,      4.3,     9.2,     6.2,         3.2,   6.4,      2.1,    1.9,  8)
fillcol <- c( 8.5,      8.3,     1.2,     3.2,         8.2,   2.4,      2.6,    6.1,  3.2)
myd <- data.frame (indvidual, Parent1, Parent2, X, Y, pchsize,fillcol)

 indvidual Parent1 Parent2   X Y pchsize fillcol
1      John    <NA>    <NA> 2.0 3     4.5     8.5
2      Kris    <NA>    <NA> 3.0 3     4.3     8.3
3     Peter    John    Kris 2.0 2     9.2     1.2
4      King    John    Kris 3.0 2     6.2     3.2
5     Marry    John    Renu 4.0 2     3.2     8.2
6      Renu    <NA>    <NA> 5.0 3     6.4     2.4
7       Kim   Peter      Lu 1.5 1     2.1     2.6
8       Ken    <NA>    <NA> 1.0 3     1.9     6.1
9        Lu    <NA>    <NA> 1.0 2     8.0     3.2
```

I want plot something like the following, individuals points are connected to parents (Preferably different line color to Parent1 and Parent2 listed). Also pch size and pch fill is scaled to other variables pchsize and fillcol. Thus plot outline is:

[image]

Here is my progress in ggplot2:

```
require(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data=myd, aes(X, Y,fill = fillcol)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pchsize, fill = fillcol), pch = "O") +
  geom_text(aes (label = indvidual, vjust=1.25))
```

[image]

Issues unsolved: connecting lines, making size of pch big and fill color at the sametime.

Comment: I think you should create different dataframe what to connect and then use line_segment.

Comment: do you have to use ggplot2? There are other options, such as Rgraphviz and a grid-based version by P. Murrell IIRC. That being said, it could be interesting to wrap this into a stat + geom.

Comment: @baptiste gglplot2 is not necessary - I do not have idea on the options you suggested ...as the one I want to produce not just sketch but will present data in terms of size of circles, color intensity at the sametime connected related ones...Also I want a function which works overall without customizing everytime for different figures ...thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @rfan probably you  create group variable (family) that consists of Individual and both of its parents, then connect family wise ...

Comment: Not a true answer, but you may want to keep an eye at: https://www.coursera.org/course/sna
The course description indicates that some of the topics regarding social networks will be addressed with the help of R in this course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that jumped out to me was to treat this is a network - R has many packages to plot these.

Here's a very simple solution:
First, I used your parent list to make a sociomatrix - you can generally input networks using edge lists as well - here I put 1 for the first parental relationship and 2 for the second.

```
psmat <- rbind(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
          rep(0, 9),
          rep(0, 9),
          c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          rep(0, 9),
          rep(0, 9),
          c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0))
```

Then, using the network package I just hit:

```
require(network)
plot(network(psmat), coord = cbind(X, Y), vertex.cex = pchsize, 
  vertex.col = fillcol, label = indvidual, edge.col = psmat)
```

This isn't terribly pretty in itself, but I think gives you all the basic elements you wanted.

For the colors, I believe the decimal places are just rounded - I wasn't sure what to do with those.

I know I've seen people plot networks in ggplot, so that might give you a better result.

[image: example picture]

Edit:
So here's a really messy way of turning your data into a network object directly - someone else might be able to fix it.  Additionally, I add an edge attribute (named 'P' for parental status) and give the first set a value of 1 and the second set a value of 2.  This can be used when plotting to set the colors.

```
P1 <- match(Parent1, indvidual)
e1 <- cbind(P1, 1:9); e1 <- na.omit(e1); attr(e1, 'na.action') <- NULL
P2 <- match(Parent2, indvidual)
e2 <- cbind(P2, 1:9); e2 <- na.omit(e2); attr(e2, 'na.action') <- NULL

en1 <- network.initialize(9)
add.edges(en1, e1[,1], e1[,2])
set.edge.attribute(en1, 'P', 1)
add.edges(en1, e2[,1], e2[,2], names.eval = 'P', vals.eval = 2)

plot(en1, coord = cbind(X, Y), vertex.cex = pchsize, 
  vertex.col = fillcol, label = indvidual, edge.col = 'P')
```

Comment: thanks, interesting option, however it is difficult to automate for real data unless can find a way to generate the psmat

Comment: Updated to make it automated.

Comment: can we replace 9 as nrows (myd) and 1:9 as 1:nrows (myd)

Answer (score 3):

Here is ggplot2 solution

```
library(ggplot2)
individual <- c("John",  "Kris", "Peter",  "King",  "Marry",  "Renu", "Kim",    "Ken", "Lu")
Parent1 <- c(    NA,     NA,     "John",  "John",   "John",    NA,    "Peter",  NA,    NA)
Parent2 <- c(    NA,     NA,    "Kris",   "Kris",  "Renu",   NA,      "Lu",     NA,   NA)
X <-       c(    2,     3,       2,       3,           4,     5,        1.5,      1,    1)
Y <-       c(    3,     3,       2,       2,           2,     3,        1,      3,    2)
pchsize <- c( 4.5,      4.3,     9.2,     6.2,         3.2,   6.4,      2.1,    1.9,  8)
fillcol <- c( 8.5,      8.3,     1.2,     3.2,         8.2,   2.4,      2.6,    6.1,  3.2)
myd <- data.frame (individual, Parent1, Parent2, X, Y, pchsize,fillcol)

SegmentParent1 <- merge(
  myd[, c("individual", "X", "Y")], 
  myd[!is.na(myd$Parent1), c("Parent1", "X", "Y")], 
  by.x = "individual", by.y = "Parent1")
SegmentParent2 <- merge(
  myd[, c("individual", "X", "Y")], 
  myd[!is.na(myd$Parent1), c("Parent2", "X", "Y")], 
  by.x = "individual", by.y = "Parent2")
Segments <- rbind(SegmentParent1, SegmentParent2)

ggplot(data=myd, aes(X, Y)) + 
  geom_segment(data = Segments, aes(x = X.x, xend = X.y, y = Y.x, yend = Y.y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = pchsize, colour = fillcol)) + 
  geom_text(aes (label = indvidual), vjust = 0.5, colour = "red", fontface = 2) + 
  scale_x_continuous("", expand = c(0, 0.6), breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous("", expand = c(0, 0.4), breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_size(range = c(20, 40)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution just using `plot()`, `text()`, and `arrows()`. The `for` loop is a bit cluttered, but will work for larger data sets and it should be easy to play with the plot and arrows:

```
plot(myd$X,myd$Y, col='white', type="p", main="", ylab="", xlab="",
    axes = FALSE, ylim = c(min(myd$Y)*.8, max(myd$Y)*1.2),
    xlim = c(min(myd$X)*.8, max(myd$X)*1.2))

child = data.frame()
child = myd[!is.na(myd$Parent1),]
DArrows = matrix(0,nrow(child),4);
MArrows = matrix(0,nrow(child),4);

for (n in 1:nrow(child)){
    d<-child[n,];
    c1<-myd$indvidual==as.character(d$Parent1);
    b1<-myd[t(c1)];
    c2<-myd$indvidual==as.character(d$Parent2);
    b2<-myd[t(c2)];
    DArrows[n, 1]=as.double(d$X)
    DArrows[n, 2]=as.double(d$Y)
    DArrows[n, 3]=as.double(b1[4])
    DArrows[n, 4]=as.double(b1[5])    
    MArrows[n, 1]=as.double(d$X)
    MArrows[n, 2]=as.double(d$Y)
    MArrows[n, 3]=as.double(b2[4])
    MArrows[n, 4]=as.double(b2[5])
}

arrows(DArrows[,3],DArrows[,4],DArrows[,1],DArrows[,2],lwd= 2, col = "blue",length=".1")
arrows(MArrows[,3],MArrows[,4],MArrows[,1],MArrows[,2],lwd=2, col = "red",length=".1")

par(new=TRUE)

plot(myd$X,myd$Y,type = "p", main = "", ylab = "", xlab = "",cex = myd$pchsize,
axes = FALSE, pch = 21, ylim = c(min(myd$Y)*.8, max(myd$Y)*1.2),
xlim=c(min(myd$X)*.8, max(myd$X)*1.2), bg = myd$fillcol,fg = 'black')

text(1.12*myd$X, .85*myd$Y, myd$indvidual)

arrows((DArrows[,3]+DArrows[,1])/2, (DArrows[,4]+DArrows[,2])/2,
    DArrows[,1], DArrows[,2], lwd = 2, col = "blue", length = ".1")
arrows((MArrows[,3]+MArrows[,1])/2, (MArrows[,4]+MArrows[,2])/2,
    MArrows[,1], MArrows[,2], lwd = 2, col = "red", length = ".1")
```

[image]

Comment: The arrow portion is not working for me..should i need some specific package loaded ....

Comment: I don't think so: `arrows`, like `segments`, `lines`, etc. is in the graphics package, which should be a defailt package (check by `getOption("defaultPackages")` or just load the package. Otherwise you can use `arrows` from the shape library, which may be better because you can modify the arrow more.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution use igraph

```
library(igraph)
mm<-data.frame(dest=c(as.character(myd$Parent1),as.character(myd$Parent2)))
mm$orig<-myd$individual
g<-graph.edgelist(as.matrix(mm[!is.na(mm$dest),]))
rownames(myd)<-as.character(myd[,1])
l<-as.matrix(myd[V(g)$name,4:5])
plot(g,layout=l,vertex.color=myd[V(g)$name,6],vertex.size=myd[V(g)$name,6])
```

[image]

Just play a bit with color a sizes!

Comment: thanks, probably need to work on the position of text may be to left or right of current position

Comment: Sure, just add.vertices(g,"Ken") should do the job (Ken is an isolated node and since I use edgelist constructor, I missed it. In a more general solution, you could do add.vertice(g,myd$individuals[!myd$individuals %in% V(g)$name])